# Setting up Dockerfile and Docker Compose for full stack project

Tags: c#, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, .net-6.0

I'm trying my hand at a full stack project using .Net 6 for the backend API with a react FE.

My project structure is this:

```
.
├── MySolution.sln
├── docker-compose.yml
└── api
    ├── MyApi.csproj
    └── Dockerfile
└── web
    └── Dockerfile
```

I have it set up and running so that my db is running and I can access it on my local machine, and the FE spins up fine in the browser. However, I can't work out how to get the api to mount so it can be accessible via an API call from the FE.

When i run `docker-compose up -d` it hangs and times out trying to build from the `Dockerfile` when it gets to the restore nuget packages section.

If i remove that line from the `Dockerfile` it then gets stuck on the following build line.

My `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  web: 
    build: ./web
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
  api:
    build: ./api
    ports:
      - 5001:5001
    environment:
      DB_URL: http://localhost:5001/api/
  db:
    container_name: apidb
    hostname: mssql-db
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
      MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD: "PassW0rd!"
      MSSQL_PID: "Express"
    ports: 
      - "1433:1433"
```

My `Dockerfile` (api)

```
# Use an official .NET runtime as a base image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base

# Set the working directory in the container to /app
WORKDIR /

# Expose ports 80 and 443 in the container
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

# Pull the .NET 6.0 SDK image from Microsofts container registry
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build

# Set the working directory in the container to /src
WORKDIR /

# Copy the source code from the host machine to the container
COPY ["MyApi.csproj", "./"]
# Restore Nuget packages for the project
RUN dotnet restore "./MyApi.csproj"
# Copy the rest of your application code to the container
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/."
# Build the project in Release configuration and output the application to /app/build
RUN dotnet build "MyApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
# Name the current stage of the build as 'publish'
FROM build AS publish
# Publish the applicationin Release configuration to a folder named 'publish'
RUN dotnet publish "MyApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

# NAme the current stage of the build as final
FROM base AS final
# Change working directory in the container to '/app'
WORKDIR /
# Copy the application from the 'publish' stage to the current stage
COPY --from=publish /publish .
# Set the command that will be run when Docker container is started
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApi.dll"]
```

Comment: Unless it's a typo transferring it to the post, you've got invalid yaml syntax at services/api/build. Did you miss the "ports" property?

Comment: sorry yes. typo

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue relates to setting the working directory to `/` in the `build` stage. Try using `/app` rather. So, for example, the top of your `Dockerfile` might look like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base

WORKDIR /

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build

WORKDIR /app

COPY MyApi.csproj .

RUN dotnet restore ./MyApi.csproj
```

You should find that works fine. But to test my hypothesis you can change `WORKDIR /app` to `WORKDIR /`, where you should find that it gets stuck again.